# How do I use the onkeypress() and listen() functions to carry out a task in which the meanings of the keys change when I press a certain key?

Tags: python, keyboard-events, python-turtle

I'm trying to create a program in python that allows the user to make an image on a grid using a turtle, from the turtle import, as a paint brush and the arrow keys to move the turtle. (This part works fine and I have functions to do this that I don't think are relevant for this question). The user should be able to change the colour of the brush by typing a number e.g. the user types *02* to change the colour to blue or *21* to change the colour to yellow. The user should be able to do this without having to type it into the shell (if that's the correct term) and press enter. The problem is I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried using the *listen()* function from the turtle library like so:

```
import keyboard
from turtle import *

def change_colour(colour):
    a.pen(pencolor=colour, fillcolor=colour)
    onkeypress(zero, "0")
    onkeypress(one, "1")
    onkeypress(two, "2")
    onkeypress(None, "3")
    onkeypress(None, "4")
    onkeypress(None, "5")
    onkeypress(None, "6")
    onkeypress(None, "7")
    onkeypress(None, "8")
    onkeypress(None, "9")
    listen()
    
def zero():
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "1")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "2")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "3")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "4")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "5")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "6")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "7")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "8")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "9")
    listen()

def one():
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "0")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "1")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "2")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "3")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "4")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "5")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "6")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "7")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "8")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "9")
    listen()

def two():
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "0")
    onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "1")
    listen()

a = Turtle()

onkeypress(zero, "0")
onkeypress(one, "1")
onkeypress(two, "2")
listen()
```

(I had to rewrite the code which is why I've written *change_colour(colour)* every time instead of the colour that it should be)

The code isn't acting as it should be and changes the turtle's colour to the last colour in the function every time I type a number e.g. I type *0* and the colour changes to green which is 09. (Typing a number that isn't 0, 1 or 2 does nothing). The program should wait for me to type 0, 1 or 2, then take me to the corresponding function, then wait for me to type a number that appears in that function, then change the colour of the turtle to the colour that corresponds with the number I just typed and then finally reset the keys so that I can change the colour again. I should also note that when I try to use any sort of infinite loop with a function from the keyboard library in it the program stops responding. I think I need to use some sort of event loop but I'm not sure how they work or how to use them

Any solutions for my main question or for how to stop my program not responding would be greatly appreciated, especially if it has an example of the code attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `listen()` more than once makes no difference (unless you lose listener window status due to calling `textinput()` or `numinput()`.)

One significant problem with your code is this invocation:

```
onkeypress(change_colour(colour), "1")
```

If your intent is to call `change_colour()` with argument `colour` when `"1"` is pressed, this won't work.  The usual way to call `onkeypress()` is more like:

```
onkeypress(change_colour, "1")
```

However, that doesn't allow you to pass in your `colour` argument.  There are various work-arounds for this, one you might try is simply:

```
onkeypress(lambda: change_colour(colour), "1")
```

I'm partial the the `partial()` routine from the **functools** library as another way of solving this problem.  However, I don't see where in your code `colour` is set so this alone might not solve your problem.